# Whats the best way to build a public API on top of an internal API?

Tags: api, design-patterns, architecture

We have a Rails app which doesn't generate any HTML - it just processes requests and responds in JSON. So it is basically an API that is used by our webapp (which renders HTML client side), iPhone app and Android app.

Now we need to build a public API and to promote code reuse, we'd like to use the internal API.

So basically we'll need to call 1-3 endpoints of this internal API, process the received requests and return data. I was hoping to get some design advice.

Here are some solutions

1. Call the internal API controllers from the public API controller. All the internal API controller however render json instead of returning data so it might be tricky.
2. Create a new Rails app, put it on a subdomain and make requests. Possible issues with latency and cross domain requests.
3. Extract out all code from the controllers into methods in the controller returning data and use these methods both for the internal API and public API (lots of refactoring)

Comment: What is the public API going to return?